# Is the Wii U compatible with Gamecube games?

Tags: backwards-compatibility, nintendo-gamecube, wii-u

So despite some initial confusion about whether the Wii U was an accessory or a console successor to the Wii, I now understand that it *is*, in fact, a new console.

During its initial presentation, Nintendo lavished about the fact that the Wii U would be fully backwards compatible, at least with the Wii.

I have also heard that it will use similar disc-based technology as its predecessor, and I was wondering if that applied to the Gamecube mini-discs as well (which the Wii was able to play).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

According to the [specifications](http://e3.nintendo.com/hw/#/about) found on Nintendo's E3 website, the drive doesn't accept GameCube's small 8cm discs, only the new high-density discs for Wii U and the normal 12cm Wii discs - so no, it won't be compatible.

This also fits with the likely strategy they use for backwards compatibility; they shut all the new stuff off so the console behaves just like the Wii - that's how they do it on the Wii for GC stuff, on the 3DS for DS stuff, and on the DS for GBA stuff. AFAIK, that technique doesn't work very well if you're trying to chain it like this, since the Wii part would have to turn all of *its* stuff off to switch to GameCube mode, and that ends up getting way too messy.

Comment: I'm not certain (as the site linked is originally in Japanese) but my impression from it via google translate was that gamecube minidiscs were simply not mentioned (either yea *or* nay).

Comment: @Raven: There hasn't been an explicit statement about it, but the fact that they didn't mention it is a pretty good indication that it won't support it. They also mention support for Wii controllers on that specification page, but no mention of GameCube controllers - and there's really no reason they'd keep that particular point from us. It's incredibly unlikely that Wii U will suddenly turn out to be backwards compatible with the GameCube.

Comment: From the pictures, I don't see any gamecube controller ports.

Comment: @BlueRaja - that would actually be my 2nd question, though there did appear to be a covered hatch a-la the Wii's GCN tab. It could just be the USB ports' cover, however.

Comment: @Raven: I've only seen the one image Nintendo have posted themselves - are you talking about the covered hatch on the front, below the disc slot? That's not big enough to hide both GameCube controller and memory card ports; it's more likely to be hiding the SD card (the Wii has its SD slot in the same basic place).

Comment: @Michael - you're probably right.

Comment: The DSi is the same generation as the DS though, and they don't actually play games any differently. Did you mean the 3DS?

Comment: @Ullallulloo: Er, yes - I did indeed mean the 3DS. I don't think the DSi has to do anything other than underclock the CPU; older, non-DSi-aware games would be unlikely to access the parts of memroy that relates to new features.

Comment: I'm sure Nintendo would be thrilled to sell you downloadable versions of all your favorite GameCube games, though.

Comment: @Brant: Even if the Wii U ends up being powerful enough to emulate the GameCube, I don't think they're planning on that. GameCube discs stored up to 1.5GB of data, and that's a lot of stuff to put in the internal memory or on an SD card. I know they'll allow you to attach a USB hard drive, but I don't think they'll do something that practically *requires* a hard drive.

Answer (score 23):

Here's a short [article](http://www.giantbomb.com/news/wii-u-does-not-play-gamecube-games/3356/) with confirmation from a Nintendo source that the Wii U will not be able to play Gamecube games.

Comment: GameCube will be two generations old at that point. At some point they have to stop supporting the old stuff.

Answer (score 3):

From what information has been released so far, the system does not accept the 8cm GameCube discs, nor does it have ports for the controllers/memory cards.

However, this doesn't rule out alternate means of playing GameCube games on the WiiU, such as with direct downloads (a la Wii's Virtual Console).

Comment: But then you have to buy the games again. I would say if you have a Wii, keep it; the Wii-U will be an HD console (finally) and as such you'll want to use HDMI for it anyway, so you can keep your Component-in for the "classic" Wii.

Answer (score 1):

While not official, Nintendon't is WiiU homebrew that will allow for the playing of Gamecube ISO's, so you could use your Wii to rip your own discs and play them on the WiiU. This homebrew even supports the gamecube adapter.

Comment: As long as your not illegaly downloading games, its perfectly fine.

Answer (score -1):

They've said that the Gamecube games will be released as DLC on the eShop.

Comment: Can you provide a link to that? Sounds new to me

Comment: @JohnoBoy - I don't have a link handy but I also remember reading an article that said GCN would be on the eShop.  Probably announced at TGS.

Comment: @JohnoBoy well I don't know if my memory is betraying me, but at the time is just a tease of the possibility by Reggie: http://kotaku.com/5944545/10-gamecube-games-that-should-be-downloadable-on-wii-u